# Flutter XCode Failed to Code Sign Release

Tags: flutter, xcode, release, codesign

target: release_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception failed to codesign

Hi guys, I have been trying to solve this issue for some time now. I have already spent quite a long time time trying to fix this issue. I have deleted the flutter build folder, done flutter clean, deleted derived data, deleted pod cache. Also tried running with —-no—tree-shake-icons but nothing worked.

This issue happens because I am trying to build an IPA for firebase so I can distribute the app. Same issue happens when I try to archive the app and distribute it to TestFlight.

I have also deleted the certificates and re used them created a proper distribution profile. I can tell it works because I am able to build the release variant of a brand new flutter app just fine.

Below is an image of the issue happening.

[image]